# Use constant for Azure Datalake domain name

Tags: c#, azure, azure-data-lake

Is there a way to use a constant from the Microsoft.Azure.DataLake.Store Nuget package (or elsewhere) to specify the Azure Data Lake Store domain name without hardcoding `{dataLakeName}.azuredatalakestore.net` into the codebase ?

I'm using `AdlsClient.CreateClient(dataLakeFqdn, serviceCredentials);`

Comment: what do you mean use a constant? can you explain it more?

Comment: Like string.Empty instead of "". It would look like Microsoft.Azure.DataLake.Store.AzureDataLakeDomainName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

You can go through the [source code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-data-lake-store-net).

For method `AdlsClient.CreateClient(dataLakeFqdn, serviceCredentials);`, it's [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-data-lake-store-net/blob/f433f28c978087bab92223ca4f54bafe02b173f5/AdlsDotNetSDK/ADLSClient.cs#L264). And inside the method, it calls the constuctor method `new AdlsClient(accountFqdn, Interlocked.Increment(ref _atomicClientId), creds);`.

When you nav to the constructor mentioned above, it's listed [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-data-lake-store-net/blob/f433f28c978087bab92223ca4f54bafe02b173f5/AdlsDotNetSDK/ADLSClient.cs#L201) in source code. And inside the constructor method, you can see it calls `IsValidAccount` method. And [IsValidAccount](https://github.com/Azure/azure-data-lake-store-net/blob/f433f28c978087bab92223ca4f54bafe02b173f5/AdlsDotNetSDK/ADLSClient.cs#L225) method only do a regular expression match operation: `return Regex.IsMatch(accnt, @"^[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9\-][a-zA-Z0-9.\-]*$");`.

**Or** you can just directly search `azuredatalakestore.net` in [source code here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-data-lake-store-net), and set search scope to "in this repository". In the search result, no `azuredatalakestore.net` is defined by sdk. You can follow this screenshot for search:

[image]

---

No.

Since the `dataLakeName` is provided by you, how does SDK or other methods know the dataLakeName without your input or hard-code it there?

And I'm not sure why you're going to avoid hard-coding the `{dataLakeName}.azuredatalakestore.net`, and here the hard-coding should be the easiest / simple way.

If you have any concerns, please let me know.

Comment: So there not reference to azuredatalakestore.net in the package ?